# Docker Compose Link

Tags: docker

Estou utilizando o Docker Compose para subir um conjunto de três contêineres "Selenium Grid":

```
selenium-hub:
  image: selenium/hub
  container_name: selenium-hub
  ports:
    - 4444:4444

nodeff:
  image: selenium/node-firefox
  ports:
    - 5900
  links:
    - selenium-hub:hub

nodechrome:
  image: selenium/node-chrome
  ports:
    - 5900
  links:
    - selenium-hub:hub
```

O Grid funciona perfeitamente. Mas quando eu preciso subir um outro contêiner com o "maven", utilizando outro Docker Compose File, passando o parâmetro link como "selenium-hub:hub", o processo falha.

Docker Compose File do Maven:

```
maven-test:
 build: .
 volumes:
  - ./Screenshots:/MeuProjeto/Screenshots
 links:
  - selenium:hub
```

Docker File do Maven:

```
FROM maven

#RUN mkdir /NaturaSiteNG

#WORKDIR /NaturaSiteNG

#COPY . /NaturaSiteNG

ENTRYPOINT curl http://selenium-hub:4444
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
ERROR: Service 'maven-test' has a link to service 'selenium:hub' which is undefined.
```

Mas ao subir o contêiner direto pelo "docker run", tudo funciona perfeitamente.

```
docker run -it --link selenium-hub:hub maven
```

O que será que estou configurando errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O *compose* irá sempre criar uma rede para seus *services* e é aqui que está o problema, já que por padrão você não conseguirá acessar container de redes distintas que não a `default`.
 O `docker run` sempre irá colocar o *container* na rede `default`, se não especificada outra, então por isso que criando assim você conseguiu o acesso.

Para construir a imagem e criar o *container* a partir da *compose* de forma que consiga acessar um container em outra rede - *service* definido em outra *compose* você tem algumas formas de fazer, tenha sempre em mente as redes. A forma mais simples é usando [`external_links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external_links) e `network_mode` como `bridge`. Neste caso, altere nas suas *composes* para algo como isto:

- *maven compose*:

```
maven-test:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./Screenshots:/MeuProjeto/Screenshots
  network_mode: bridge
  external_links:
    - selenium-hub:hub
```

- *selenium compose*:

```
selenium-hub:
  image: selenium/hub
  container_name: selenium-hub
  network_mode: bridge
  ports:
    - 4444:4444
```

Aqui o que fazemos basicamente é que todos os serviços funcionem no modo de rede *bridge*, então independente da rede que esteja irá enxergá-lo, já que é uma rede "agregada".

Outra forma é usando na *compose* do *maven* a rede criada na *compose* do *selenium*: neste caso vou assumir que a rede criada se chama `selenium_default`, na *compose* do *selenium* não é necessário alteração, apenas na do *maven*:

```
maven-test:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./Screenshots:/MeuProjeto/Screenshots
  external_links:
    - selenium-hub:hub
  networks:
    - selenium_default
networks:
  selenium_default:
    external: true
```

Nesta segunda forma fizemos com que o serviço do *maven* seja parte de uma rede externa, a criada pela *compose* do *selenium*. Observe também como você irá referenciar o outro container na construção da sua imagem, use o *alias* se informado, etc.

Há outras formas de fazer, como criar uma rede explicitamente interna ou externamente às *compose*, dê uma olhada em como funcionam as redes e veja a que melhor se adequa a você.