# Duvida quanto a comunicação entre containers

Tags: docker

Tenho uma dúvida quanto a comunicação entre containers, no meu docker-compose estou criando um link entre o container **web** e **mysql**. Esse link seria uma rede interna?

Se não, seria mais performático criar uma rede interna?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SENHA
      MYSQL_DATABASE: webApp
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: senha
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: web_dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-web
    volumes:
      - ../Desenvolvimento Web/:/var/www
      - ./Apache/:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
    working_dir: /var/www
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Comment: Não é a mesma dúvida que a sua, mas respondi algo neste sentido aqui, sobre as redes em uma compose: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243881/docker-compose-link/243957#243957

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Essa instrução Links que eu utilizei, faz exatamente o que?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O link representa simplesmente uma entrada no HOSTS do seu container. Como a informação de link vai para o metadado do container, sempre que você vai subir esse container o docker descobre o IP correto do container "linkado" e acerta o arquivo HOSTS do container que depende do link. Esse processo faz com que seu container não precise resolver o nome em um IP, ele simplesmente "sabe".

Uma rede, no docker é literalmente uma rede virtual. A rede bridge por exemplo, (exceto a default) faz resolução de nomes automaticamente, isso significa que ao invés do seu container simplesmente saber qual é o IP, é o drive da rede quem responde com a informação atual.

Você pode inspecionar suas redes usando os subcomandos do `docker network`, como `docker network ls` por exemplo..

Comment: Outro ponto interessante é que você pode ver esse metadado, usando o `docker inspect [containerName] `

Comment: existe diferença de performance entre essas abordagens? Por exemplo, seria mas performático adicionar estes contêineres a uma rede virtual?

Comment: Não sei responder. Nunca achei nada que fizesse esse contraponto. Até pq acho que estamos falando da mesma implementação, o que faria ter performance semelhante.