# Quando o container não sabe o nome do host?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, docker

Criei um container no docker e ele tenta acessar um host chamada pgmaster. Na maquina onde está instalado o docker eu adicionei o sequinte host: `10.0.0.3 pgmaster` no `/etc/hosts`. Tanto quando vou tentar fazer um ssh funciona perfeitamente: `ssh vini@pgmaster`. Porém quando meu container tenta acessar o pg master:

`psql: could not translate host name "pgmaster" to address:  Name or service not known`

Sim, meu container está tentando acessar um postgresql na maquina pgmaster. Tanto que este comando funciona perfeitamente na maquina principal: `psql mydb -h pgmaster -p 5432`

Existe algum lugar nos containers que devo setar os nomes dos hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os containers não tem conhecimento de *hosts* que estão fora das redes nas quais o *container* está. Este é seu problema, ou seja, o *docker host* - sua máquina - conhece o `pgmaster`, mas não o *container*. Veja nesta resposta como é o funcionamento de [*networks*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243881/docker-compose-link/243957#243957)

Para o seu problema, ao criar o *container* você pode adicionar uma entrada ao `/etc/hosts` do *container*, como abaixo:

```
docker run -d -p 90:80 --add-host pgmaster:10.0.0.3 nginx:alpine
```

Caso esteja usando *compose*, o equivalente do acima seria isto:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx_sopt
    ports:
      - "90:80"
    extra_hosts:
      - "pgmaster:10.0.0.3"
```

Isto irá adicionar uma entrada como a abaixo:

```
10.0.0.3        pgmaster
```

O resultado no `/etc/hosts` será algo como o abaixo (`docker run --rm -it -p 90:80 --add-host pgmaster:10.0.0.3 nginx:alpine cat /etc/hosts` ou `docker-compose exec nginx cat /etc/hosts`, por exemplo):

```
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
10.0.0.3        pgmaster
172.17.0.2      ee6160c61d4d
```